# How do i update the correct user.email without reverting the latest commit?

Tags: git

I have a commit with wrong email address in .gitconfig file. I would like to update the email and commit details without reseting the HEAD to older commit hash. Is that possible with git?

Comment: Not possible. The commit sha1 is a hash of the whole commit, including the email and commit details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the latest commit use:

```
git commit --amend --author="John Doe <john@doe.org>"
```

But before use:

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

Answer (score 0):

- start an interactive rebase:

  ```
  git rebase HEAD^ -i
  ```
- then in the file opened change the word `pick` in the first line to `reword` and close the file.
- git will open another editor where you can change the autor